# Getting the new line character without System.getProperty("line.separator")?

Tags: java, file-io, newline

I want to create a text file, than load it up without any newlines or spaces (This is for a simple RPG). So I want to test for all 3 major OS line separators, and than the current OS'(s?) one.  I know I can get the current one using System.getProperty("line.separator"),  but how can I get Linux, Mac, and Windows line separators and turn them into a string for Java?

Edit: I need a single character representation of these, because for some reason "\n" doesn't work (Yes I'm on windows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are `"\n"` (Linux and MacOS X), `"\r"` (MacOS 9 and older) and `"\r\n"` (Windows).

Just hard-code them - they're not going to change!  :-)

**Edit:** There's no "single character representation" of `"\r\n"` - it's two characters.

Answer (score 18):

Java 7 now has a [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) method.

See [Java: How do I get a platform independent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207950/639687)

Answer (score -2):

there's no "getter" for these, you just need to copy the strings off the internet into your own constants.