# How to get surrounding method in Java source file for a given line number

Tags: java, parsing

I have a line number of a Java source file and want to get the surrounding method for that line number programmatically.

Comment: Do you want to parse the source file manually?

Comment: Good luck! Feel free to share your results with us!

Comment: After the fact, or would you like a solution for future runs?

Comment: This will get difficult. What would you do for example in the case of anonymous inner classes (i.e., methods defined in classes, which are defined inside a method of another class)? Which of the methods would you want as the output?

Answer (score 7):

Use something like [JavaParser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/). From what I can see, the [Node](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/source/browse/trunk/JavaParser/src/japa/parser/ast/Node.java) class has references to begin and end column and row indexes. [MethodDeclaration](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/source/browse/trunk/JavaParser/src/japa/parser/ast/body/MethodDeclaration.java) is a subclass of Node, so parse the source file and search for the MethodDeclaration that 'contains' your line number.

### Sample code

You would make sure the `src` file points to your own source. Here, I just use the source of the sample itself.

```
package grimbo.test;

import japa.parser.JavaParser;
import japa.parser.ParseException;
import japa.parser.ast.CompilationUnit;
import japa.parser.ast.body.MethodDeclaration;
import japa.parser.ast.visitor.VoidVisitorAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMethodLineNumber {
    public static void method1() {
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void method2() {
        String s = "hello";
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        File f = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile();
        File srcRoot = new File(f, "src/main/java");
        String srcFilename = TestMethodLineNumber.class.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".java";
        File src = new File(srcRoot, srcFilename);
        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(srcRoot);
        System.out.println(src);
        getMethodLineNumbers(src);
    }

    private static void getMethodLineNumbers(File src) throws ParseException, IOException {
        CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(src);
        new MethodVisitor().visit(cu, null);
    }

    /**
     * Simple visitor implementation for visiting MethodDeclaration nodes.
     */
    private static class MethodVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter {
        @Override
        public void visit(MethodDeclaration m, Object arg) {
            System.out.println("From [" + m.getBeginLine() + "," + m.getBeginColumn() + "] to [" + m.getEndLine() + ","
                    + m.getEndColumn() + "] is method:");
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }
}
```

### Sample output

```
From [13,5] to [16,5] is method:
public static void method1() {
    int i = 1;
    System.out.println(i);
}
From [18,5] to [21,5] is method:
public static void method2() {
    String s = "hello";
    System.out.println(s);
}
From [23,5] to [32,5] is method:
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
    File f = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile();
    File srcRoot = new File(f, "src/main/java");
    String srcFilename = TestMethodLineNumber.class.getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".java";
    File src = new File(srcRoot, srcFilename);
    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.println(srcRoot);
    System.out.println(src);
    getMethodLineNumbers(src);
}
From [34,5] to [37,5] is method:
private static void getMethodLineNumbers(File src) throws ParseException, IOException {
    CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(src);
    new MethodVisitor().visit(cu, null);
}
From [43,9] to [48,9] is method:
@Override
public void visit(MethodDeclaration m, Object arg) {
    System.out.println("From [" + m.getBeginLine() + "," + m.getBeginColumn() + "] to [" + m.getEndLine() + "," + m.getEndColumn() + "] is method:");
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand exactly how to do what you just told me

Comment: @Paul Btw is a java new line a CRLF or a LF ?

Comment: @Pacerier - I believe it varies according to the O/S. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character

Comment: @PaulGrime no I was talking about the Java source code.. I've found it here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html

Comment: Is it also possible to get Line number of instructions running inside each method with a small touch? @Paul Grime

Comment: it works like a charm. And you need to replace m.getBeginLine() with m.getRange().get().begin.line  in the new version of JavaParser

Answer (score 0):

For the new version of JavaParser:

```
    @Override
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration m, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("From [" + m.getRange().get().begin.line + "," + m.getRange().get().begin.column
            + "] to [" + m.getRange().get().end.line + "," + m.getRange().get().end.column + "] is method:");
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```