# How to be able to identify a constructor using JavaParser?

Tags: java, parsing, constructor

I am using Java Parser to get information about the method in a source file. I based my implementation as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360311/how-to-get-surrounding-method-in-java-source-file-for-a-given-line-number) . However the details of constructors are not being given. I think it has to do with how the Java parser works as the normal methods have a return type and the constructor doesn't.

Does anyone know how to be able to also get information of constructors using the Java parser?

Comment: Constructors are not methods, they only look so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for a symbol that's the same as the class name. All constructors are of the type public classname(args) or private classname(args). No return, and no class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstructorDeclaration instead of MethodDeclaration