# is there a way to get information about the constructor using JavaParser or some other API?

Tags: java, parsing, constructor

I need to be able to get information about the constructor of a source file, for example the beging line number, and maybe some lines that are within the constructor. I am using a similar idea for the methods of a file in order to be able to get the begin and end line numbers and the names of the methods. For this im using the JavaParser as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360311/how-to-get-surrounding-method-in-java-source-file-for-a-given-line-number).

I could not find a way to be able to use the JavaParser for my aim. Is there a way to be able to get similar information of the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

You can get information about the constructor the same way you do it with method declarations:

```
CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(file);
    List<TypeDeclaration> typeDeclarations = cu.getTypes();
    for (TypeDeclaration typeDec : typeDeclarations) {
        List<BodyDeclaration> members = typeDec.getMembers();
        if(members != null) {
            for (BodyDeclaration member : members) {
                if (member instanceof ConstructorDeclaration) {
                    ConstructorDeclaration constructor = (ConstructorDeclaration) member;
                    //Put your code here
                    //The constructor instance contains all the information about it. 

                    constructor.getBeginLine(); //begin line
                    constructor.getBlock(); //constructor body
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the Java perser from Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT). There is an excellent tutorial with code examples by Lars Vogel: [Eclipse JDT - Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the Java Model - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html#jdt_ast) on how to parse java code.

You can get the [IMethod](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMethod.html) for every constructor and then call `getSourceRange()` and `getSource()` on it.