# How can I break the string on Java?

Tags: java

I need to write strings into `ByteArrayOutputStream`, but I need to write strings with breaking. I have tried to do it as example:

```
out.write("123".getBytes());
out.write("\n456".getBytes());
```

But '\n' doesn't work. Please, tell me, how can I fix it? Or suggest me alternative OutputStream for storing strings (this OS must allow to use breaking of lines) without making files. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by breaking?

Comment: I mean that each string is another line on file.

Comment: Which OS? If it's Windows you might need "\r\n" for a linebreak if you're writing it as bytes, depending on what you then try to read the file with.

Comment: What is "this OS"?  Maybe you need to use the newline sequence for your OS.  The LF (\n) works for unix-like OSes, but Windows uses CR-LF (\r\n).  You can find it programmatically with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character

Comment: Please clarify your statement that "'\n' doesn't work". It *does* work, in that it does exactly what it's supposed to. The problem is that you want something different . . . but you haven't said what that is.

Comment: @Fly: "this OS" must mean "this OutputStream", i.e., the "alternative OutputStream for storing strings" that the OP is soliciting suggestions for.

Answer (score 7):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = ...;
PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(stream, true); // auto-flush
printer.println("123"); // writes newline
printer.print("hello"); // no new line
printer.print(" world");
printer.println();
```

Note that this will generate platform-specific bytes. Newlines can be `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r`.
The actual character sequence used is specified in [system property `line.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: @Ted true -- I *did* use `autoFlush` = `true` in the constructor, but that is only applicable when new lines are written.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after posting the comment, so I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `BufferedWriter` it will manage line breaks for you (`bwinstance.newLine()`). No matter on which OS you are running.

Comment: There's a step missing: you can't go from an OutputStream to a BufferedWriter directly. You need to already have a Writer (such as an OutputStreamWriter) to buffer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a system independent newline separator I would recommend using:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Rather than calling `getProperty()` every time, I would also store this value in a properly accessible variable.

This is also the ideal method if you are constructing strings prior to writing them, since this way you will not have to write each line separately.