# can not open files with openFileInput saved via openFileOutput

Tags: android, filestream

this is the way I write my data into a file

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("ThisWeekDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String Line;
while ((Line = thisWeekReader.readLine()) != null) {
        fos.write(Line.getBytes()); 
}
fos.close();
```

and this is the way I am trying to read that same file

```
FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput ("ThisWeekDatabase") ;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader ( fIn ) ;
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader ( isr ) ;
String Line;
while ((Line = buffreader.readLine ()) != null ) {
    if (Line.contains("xyz")){
        doSomething();
    }
}
isr.close ( ) ;
```

but I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Are you sure that your `openFileOutput()` code was called? Have you examined the file in the emulator's filesystem?

Comment: i am not using a emulator. i am using my phone and usb-debugging. yes i am sure that i call the openFileOutput(). thx

Comment: Then I humbly suggest that you try this on an emulator, so you can see whether or not the file is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            saveDataFromWeb();// here i write data into a file
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    findViewById(R.id.viewpager).getContext());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            sw.toString();
            builder.setMessage(sw.toString());
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
};
if (CONDITION) {
    thread.start();
    parseData("ThisWeekDatabase"); // here I read the data from the 
    parseData("NextWeekDatabase");
}
```

I found the error. It is because the thread is not done with it's work (writing data from the web into files) when I try to read these files. Now I need a way to "wait" for the thread so it has finished writing the files when `parseData(xyz)` needs them.

also either the way I write the data into the file or the way I read the data from the files is wrong because I get one single long line when I read out of the files I have written in before instead of multiple short lines.

I get

```
div.lvsdrt {background-color:#e3f1ff; border-top:black 1px dotted;padding:0.1em;}div.lvwer{background-color:#f2f9ff;border-top:black 1px dotted;padding:0.1em;}div.nobreak {page-break-inside:avoid;}
```

instad of

```
div.lvsdrt {
    background-color:#e3f1ff;
    border-top:black 1px dotted;
    padding:0.1em;
}
div.lvwer {
    background-color:#f2f9ff;
    border-top:black 1px dotted;
    padding:0.1em;
}
div.nobreak {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CONDITION) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                saveDataFromWeb();// here i write data into a file
            } catch (Throwable e) { // CATCH THROWABLE ??!! WHY ?
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        findViewById(R.id.viewpager).getContext());
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                e.printStackTrace(pw);
                sw.toString();
                builder.setMessage(sw.toString());
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } finally {
                latch.notify();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    latch.await();
    parseData("ThisWeekDatabase"); // here I read the data from the
    parseData("NextWeekDatabase");
}
```

As for the new lines:

```
while ((line = thisWeekReader.readLine()) != null) {
    fos.write((line + "\n").getBytes());
}
```

`\n` is just a hack - if you are on windows use `\r\n` or better yet read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

**EDIT** : if you can't make the latch work use :

```
thread.start();
try {
    thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO handle
}
parseData("ThisWeekDatabase"); // here I read the data from the
parseData("NextWeekDatabase");
```