# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in the terminating condition of a while loop

Tags: java

I get a *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException* in the terminating condition of my *while loop*. Could someone explain the reason for this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Solution {

    public static int fun(String s) {
        int count=0;
        int k,j;                 

        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {

            k=i;
            j=0;
            if (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) {
                while((s.charAt(j)==s.charAt(k))&&(k<s.length())&&(j<s.length())) {
                    j++;
                    k++;
                }
                count+=j;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner se=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=se.nextInt();
        String s;
        int a[]=new int[t];
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++) {
            s=se.nextLine();
            a[i]=fun(s);
        }   
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
           System.out.println(a[i]); 
        se.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's the job of this program? What's some input, output and expected output?

Comment: actually this is a problem from interview street https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity

Comment: @saimadan check my ans. if your rest of the logic is correct then you are done with the exception..

Comment: hey @arpit please help me with my logic i don't want to see others code

Comment: @saimadan try yourself ! if you get any error in your code, google it and still don't get it then you can use SO. No help for logic. i don't know what the ques. is.

Comment: @Arpit say me where the error is happening in the code i googled, i tried, i did a lot of things don't help me with the logic help me with the error

Comment: It is easier for the people here to give you answers, if you actually either give the exact error message (if there is one), or describe the error. Also you migth try to describe what this block of code is supposed to do.

Comment: check out this link for he question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity

Comment: @saimadan I added more details to the answer. I hope this clarified the situation for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

> java.lang 
>   Class **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**
>
> Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative
>   or greater than the size of the string. For some methods such as the
>   charAt method, this exception also is thrown when the index is equal
>   to the size of the string.

You are exceeding the length of the string.

In addition I think you have some errors in your logic (see below).

What you really are trying to do is this:

```
while ((k < s.length()) && (j < s.length())) { // While no String goes out of Bounds
    if (s.charAt(j) != s.charAt(k)) { // If we get a different character
        break; // Get out of the loop
    } else {
        j++;  // Advance one position
        k++;
    }
}
```

What you were doing was this:

```
if (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) { // If the characters are equal
    while ((s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) // While the characters are equal
              && (k < s.length()) && (j < s.length())) {  // And the position is smaller than the length
       j++;
       k++;
    }
    count += j;
}
```

The If is redundant, since you chech it in the while anyway, and count would be increased by zero.

But more importantly, in the terminating condition of the while, you the check if `s.charAt(j)` happens before the check `j < s.length()`. Thus, you get the exception at the first case, before you see if j is to large

---

In addition, since the expressions is Java are calculated from left to right, you could change your loop like this:

```
while ((k < s.length()) && (j < s.length()) && (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k))) {
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

Now you don't get an Exception, because if the first 2 terms are false (from the left), then the other two term on the right will not be evaluated at all (at least in my JVM)

Output:

```
run:
2
ababaa
aa
11
3
```

Hope that helped.

Ps: I also changed the line

```
int t = se.nextInt();
```

to

```
int t = se.nextInt();se.nextLine();
```

So that you parse the newline after the number is given.

---

***Clarifications***

*1) Why `se.nextLine()`*

You had

```
int t = se.nextInt();
```

Lets say the user enters `23` and presses  <kbd>enter</kbd>, which means that the *InputSream* whill read from the keyboard `23\n`. `23` is the number that the user entered, and `\n` is *newline* character. The *newline* character is used so that the computer can tell when one line ends and the next one begins, and it is automatically inserted when the user presses enter. More info here: [How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

When you call `nextInt()`, you only read the number that was entered, but you do not read the `\n` character. Thus, next time you call `readLine()`, you will read the `\n` that is left over from when you entered the number (and pressed enter). This is the reason you change the above command to

```
int t = se.nextInt();se.nextLine();
```

Now you read that extra `\n` character, and the next call of `nextLine()`, that will happen when you read the string that the user entered, will correctly return the string.

*2) Why did whe change the loop to `((k < s.length()) && (j < s.length()) && (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k))`*

You had this

```
( (s.charAt(j)==s.charAt(k)) && (k<s.length()) && (j<s.length()) )
```

This caused the *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException*. And here is why:

In Java, the expressions are calculated from left to right. that means, that at each iteration, the JVM will first check `(s.charAt(j)==s.charAt(k))`. If the term is *true*, then it will evaluate the term `(k<s.length())`, and if that is also *true*, it will evaluate `(j<s.length())`. If all these terms are *true*, the program will enter the loop.

On the other hand, if the first term (i.e. `(s.charAt(j)==s.charAt(k))` ) is *false*, then the whole expression is *false* (since we have and *AND* operator), and there is no need to calculate the rest of terms.

Now, why did that cause an *Exception*? Look at what happens at the last iteration. At this point, the variable `j` (or `k` equivalently) will have a value equal to the length of string `s`. When the JVM tries to evaluate the termination condition, it will first evaluate the term `(s.charAt(j)==s.charAt(k))`. Since `j` is equal to the length of `s`, the call `charAt()` will throw a *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException*, since the call will try to get a character that is **outside** of the string. Remember that the indexes in the String are from `0` to `length() - 1`. This is where you got your Exception.

If however, you change the termination condition to

```
((k < s.length()) && (j < s.length()) && (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)))
```

you will avoid the *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException*. Here is why. This time, the terms `(k < s.length())` and  `(j < s.length())` are evaluated *before* the call to `charAt()`. Thus, when we reach the end of the string, at least one of the two first terms will be `false`, and there is no need to evaluate the rest of the Expression. Thus, at the last iteration, the method `charAt` is not called at all, so we don't get the Exception.

I hope this clarified the situation a bit.

Comment: even i change while ((s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) && (k < s.length() -1 ) && (j < s.length() -1 )) { it is not working

Comment: hey can you please explain i didn't understand clearly what you said .waiting for reply

Comment: @saimadan What part would you like me to clarify?

Comment: int t = se.nextInt();se.nextLine();                                  (k < s.length()) && (j < s.length()) && (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) both these things

Comment: your explaination is very good. i think i can learn a lot from you because i'm just a beginner .please stay in touch ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        s=se.nextLine();
        se.next(); //add this to discard the newline char of nextLine(). because of newline your next string input is empty string. which leads to IOB exception.
        a[i]=fun(s);
    }
```

Output:

```
2
asdf
asdf
0
0
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the commented lines i didn't understand the purpose of se.next()