# Stdin reading multiple lines

Tags: java, stdin

I have the following code:

```
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String submittedString = "";
        System.out.flush();
        submittedString = stdin.readLine();

        int numberofLines = Integer.parseInt(submittedString.split(" ")[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < numberofLines; i++)
            submittedString += stdin.readLine();

        zipfpuzzle mySolver = new zipfpuzzle();
        mySolver.getTopSongs(submittedString);
```

However, despite the input being over multiple lines, this only reads the first.

Where is my mistake?

If it makes any difference, I am compiling on eclipse.

Cheers!
Dario

Comment: It reads all user inputs separately, but you concatenate them and see them as one string!!!

Comment: So I can I maintain linebreaks?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character on how to have platform-independent end-of-line codes.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you're passing to this?

Comment: 4 2
30 one
30 two
15 three
25 four
@ahjmorton

Comment: Sorry, should have been
4 2
30 one

30 two

15 three

25 four

Comment: ok multiline comments are not allowd, but it should be 4 2 (newline) 30 one (newline) etc

Answer (score 4):

Just use an array and populate it within your for-loop:

```
String[] inputs = new String[numberofLines];

for (int i = 0; i < numberofLines; i++)
    inputs[i] = stdin.readLine();
```

**Extra Note:**

If you want multiple lines with single String:

```
String submittedString = "";

for (int i = 0; i < numberofLines; i++)
    submittedString += stdin.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: But is it possible to have multi-line strings in Java?

Comment: @DarioPanada yes. see my extra note. denote the newline!

Comment: `"\n"` can look weird in various Windows text editors.  Consider using the `System.getProperty("line.separator");` as suggested by @PM77-1 in the question comments.

Comment: @jedwards yes, definitely. that way is better.

Answer (score 3):

```
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = "";

while ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null){
// Do something.
submittedString += line + '\n';

}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it will keep reading lines even one one is null

Answer (score -1):

```
submittedString = stdin.readLine();
```

[BufferedReaders readLine method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will read System.in until it hits a new line, therefore if you're using the first line of the file to determine the number of lines to read then your data must be incorrect.