# Not the correct input

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, io

I want to write some data to a file and here is my code:

```
for (Season s : seasons) {
            if (s.getYear() >= start && s.getYear() <= end) {
                line += s.getYear() + ", " + s.getWinTeamName() + ", "
                        + s.getMinorPremiersTeam() + ", "
                        + s.getWoodenSpoonTeam()+ "\n"; }
}
System.out.println("File created.\n"); // Informing the user about
// the creation of the file.
out.write(line);
out.close();
```

My file is created but this is what I get:

```
2005, Wests Tigers, Parramatta, Newcastle2006, Broncos, Storm, Rabbitohs
```

But I want it to be:

```
2005, Wests Tigers, Parramatta, Newcastle
2006, Broncos, Storm, Rabbitohs
```

I thought the adding the "\n" at the end of the line variable would fix that but it hasn't.

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: It seems OK. Try replacing the \n with \r\n, some text editors (Notepad, for example) don't show \n correctly.

Comment: Your println() doesn't need a `\n`. The methodname stands for `print line` so it already uses new lines.

Comment: For more generic code, you may want to use [a line separator function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the system-specific newline separator. See [System.lineSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `java.io.BufferedWriter`, the `.newLine()` method will insert the appropriate line separator.

```java
for (Season s : seasons) 
{
   if (s.getYear() >= start && s.getYear() <= end)
   {
      String line = s.getYear() + ", " + s.getWinTeamName() + ", "
                        + s.getMinorPremiersTeam() + ", "
                        + s.getWoodenSpoonTeam();
      out.write(line);
      out.newLine();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Season s : seasons) {
        if (s.getYear() >= start && s.getYear() <= end) {
            line += s.getYear() + ", " + s.getWinTeamName() + ", "
                    + s.getMinorPremiersTeam() + ", "
                    + s.getWoodenSpoonTeam()+ "\r\n"; }
}

System.out.println("File created.\n"); // Informing the user about
                                      // the creation of the file.
out.write(line);
out.close();
```