# Deciding newline character at runtime

Tags: java

I am reading a file with one paragraph at a time seperated by a newline.

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

Here I read Lines 1, 2, 3 and then Lines 4, 5, 6.

```
while (there are still more paragraphs) {
  String paragraph = new Scanner(new File("testdata.txt")).useDelimiter("\n\n").next();
}
```

The delimeter "\n\n" is to identify paragraph and not a line. Now, the delimiter can change into "\r\n\r\n" in few systems and "\n\n" in other few. Is there any way to identify it at runtine and use it? I am looking for something like:

```
String delimiter = getNewLineCharYourself();
String paragraph = new Scanner(new File("testdata.txt")).useDelimiter(delimiter).next();
```

Comment: Detect OS and use `\r\n` (which AFAIK only Windows uses) or `\n` when appropriate?

Comment: @m0skit0 don't reinvent the wheel. Check the answer below.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Who said he had to implement it himself? That's just a hint ;)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for

```
System.getProperty("line.seperator");
```

Comment: or `System.lineSeparator()` anyway +1

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
String newLine = String.format("%n"); 
//       %n becomes newline     ^^
```

Or:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Or, in Java 7:

```
System.lineSeparator();
```

From here: [How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

Comment: should flag the question as a duplicate rather than duplicating answers!

Comment: You are totally right

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the entire file as you have it, and then split the data:

```
for ( String line : "the entire file".split( System.getProperty("line.separator") )
{
     System.out.println( line );
}
```

is the universal new line character.

An alternative method:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "absolute file path" ) );

String line;

while ( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null)
{
     System.out.println( line );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What jlordo says. Or use a `BufferedReader`:

```
File file = new File("myFile.txt");
if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                // TODO something with your line
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) {
        // TODO handle this
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        // attempting to close
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `try with resources` to get rid of that mess in `finally`?

Comment: @jlordo because I use Java 6 :D