# Create a new line in Java's FileWriter

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I have coded the following `FileWriter`:

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("file.txt"), false);

    String sizeX = jTextField1.getText();
    String sizeY = jTextField2.getText();
    writer.write(sizeX);
    writer.write(sizeY);

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Now I want to insert a new line, just like you would do it with `\n` normally, but it doesn't seem to work.

What can be done to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: `writer.write("\n");`

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` can you post results you get?

Comment: If I try the "\n" method, there's nothing... just 1254 (12 for sizeX, 54 for sizeY)...

Comment: @lukulus could you try `writer.write("\r\n");` or better `writer.write(System.lineSeparator())`?

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you want to get *new line* characters used in current OS like `\r\n` for Windows, you can get them by

- `System.getProperty("line.separator");`
- since Java7 `System.lineSeparator()`
- or as mentioned by Stewart generate them via `String.format("%n");`

---

You can also use `PrintStream` and its `println` method which will add OS dependent line separator at the end of your string automatically

```
PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(new File("file.txt"));
fileStream.println("your data");
//         ^^^^^^^ will add OS line separator after data
```

(BTW `System.out` is also instance of PrintStream).

Answer (score 33):

Try `System.getProperty( "line.separator" )`

```
   writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
```

Answer (score 13):

Try wrapping your `FileWriter` in a `BufferedWriter`:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
bw.newLine();
```

Javadocs for BufferedWriter [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String.format("%n");
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean use the same code but add a new line so that when you add something to the file it will be on a new line. You can simply use BufferedWriter's `newLine()`.
Here I have Improved you code also: NumberFormatException was unnecessary as nothing was being cast to a number data type, saving variables to use once also was.

```
try {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
        writer.write(jTextField1.getText());
        writer.write(jTextField2.getText());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("File could not be created");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since 1.8, I thought this might be an additional solution worth adding to the responses:

> *Path java.nio.file.Files.write(Path path, Iterable lines, OpenOption... options) throws IOException*

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(jTextField1.getText());
sb.append(jTextField2.getText());
sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), sb.toString().getBytes());
```

If appending to the same file, perhaps use an Append flag with Files.write()

```
Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), sb.toString().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here "\n" is also working fine. But the problem here lies in the text editor(probably notepad). Try to see the output with Wordpad.

Comment: Smart one! Worked for me and should work for assignments. However for a project, any of the above highlighted approaches should be used

Comment: yes, Notepad doesn't work with `/n`, but WordPad works fine with `/n`. Or need to use `line.separator` for Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

One can use [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to wrap the `FileWriter`, as it has many additional useful methods.

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("file.txt"), false))){
   pw.println();//new line
   pw.print("text");//print without new line
   pw.println(10);//print with new line
   pw.printf("%2.f", 0.567);//print double to 2 decimal places (without new line)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle the problem like this:

```
    BufferedWriter output;
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt", true));
    String sizeX = jTextField1.getText();
    String sizeY = jTextField2.getText();
    output.append(sizeX);
    output.append(sizeY);
    output.newLine();
    output.close();
```

The true in the FileWriter constructor allows to append.
The method newLine() is provided by BufferedWriter
Could be ok as solution?

Answer (score -1):

using simple `\n` to break line in write file and normal output in java

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything to the question, which hasn't been answered already.