# Write multiple lines into CSV

Tags: java, file-io

My value object has multiple lines say:

```
abc
xyz
pqr
mno
```

I want to convert these lines into upper case and simultaneously write into a csv file. Me below code only writes the last entry i.e. "mno" into the o/p file. Because it is overwriting over existing ones.

```
private Object transformFieldValue(Object value) throws IOException {
    String upperCase = value.toString().toUpperCase();
    File file = new File("andy.csv");
    FileWriter fr=null;

    try {
        fr = new FileWriter(file);
        fr.write(upperCase);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fr.flush();
            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return upperCase;
}
```

How to achieve the result so that andy.csv reads like:

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
MNO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: FileWriter: Create a new line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549704/java-filewriter-create-a-new-line)

Comment: What is the actual type of 'value'? Presumably it's not actually Object, but is derived from Object.

Comment: Similar to jarmod's question, I'm not seeing where you are passing in the 4 lines. Are you calling 'transformFieldValue' multiple times for each line?  |  
I'd try using `new FileWriter(file, true)`. Per the javadoc, when you pass in the 'true' parameter, "data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning."

Comment: Does the string representation of the object have carriage return (`\r`) characters in it, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

> Because it is overwriting over existing ones.

Yes, but it's overriding the file. My guess is you have an loop that calls `transformFieldValue`, each time you enter that method, you're creating a new file and a new `FileWritter`:

1. Convert your `File file` and your `FileWriter fr` members of your class (i.e. global variables).
2. Create 3 methods: `createNewFile()`, `writeToFile()`, `closeFile()`.

   a. `createNewFile()` should contain the following:

   ```
   File file = new File("andy.csv");
   FileWriter fr=null;
   try {
       fr = new FileWriter(file);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   b. `writeToFile()` should contain:

   ```
   String upperCase = value.toString().toUpperCase();
   fr.write(upperCase);
   ```

   c. `closeFile()` should contain:

   ```
   fr.flush();
   fr.close();
   ```

Add `try-catch-finally` blocks where needed

But if you want more and better help, please post a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is maybe:

Change

```
fr = new FileWriter(file);
```

to

```
fr = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

"true" will enable appending bytes to the end of the file.

Do not forget to create a line break. This may be different for differrent for different operating systems:

```
fw.write("\r\n");
```

... e.g. for windows line breaks.

BUT:

As you mentioned that it should "convert these lines into upper case and simultaneously write into a csv file" it is clearly a Violation of the Single Responsibility Principle. I suggest to put the Code on Trial in the whole on "Stack Exchange Code Review".

Comment: it gave output as ABCXYZPQRMNO