# problem writing in different lines in .txt file java

Tags: java, file

this is my code

```
File users = new File("C:\\Clients\\usernames.txt");
FileWriter usersWriter = new FileWriter(users);
usersWriter.write("user1");
usersWriter.write("user2");
usersWriter.write("user3");
usersWriter.close();
```

It doesnt write in different lines each element. it does(user1user2user3). How do i fix that?

Comment: you forgot `\n` : `usersWriter.write("user1\n"); `

Comment: im sorry this doesnt work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a new line in Java's FileWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549704/create-a-new-line-in-javas-filewriter)

Answer (score 0):

Add `+ "\r\n"` or just `"\r\n"` if string, wherever you want next line:

```
File users = new File("C:\\Clients\\usernames.txt");
FileWriter usersWriter = new FileWriter(users);
usersWriter.write("user1\r\n");
usersWriter.write("user2\r\n");
usersWriter.write("user3\r\n");
usersWriter.close();
```

Comment: i found it.. this worked for me "\r\n"

Comment: @faroquser changed the answer for your scenario. Thanks to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18549704/10313894
Please search well before asking :-)

Answer (score 0):

On windows you always need the \r\n. When you use only \n than no new line are shown.
But you can also use: the System.getProperty( "line.separator" )
This solution works on every Operatingsystem.

```
    FileWriter usersWriter = new FileWriter(users);
        usersWriter.write("user1" + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        usersWriter.write("user2" + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        usersWriter.write("user3" + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        usersWriter.close();
```