# How to make a new line on file writer?

Tags: java

I have tried \n and stuff its still not working..?
I have also tried System.lineSeparator(); it still does not work. I have reviewed other posts.

```
FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("Random.txt");
myWriter.write(saltStr);
myWriter.close();
```

Yes, I have looped the file writer.

Output file:

```
2TFPXDLDKSFZUCIP5FGUAXZU
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a new line in Java's FileWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549704/create-a-new-line-in-javas-filewriter)

Comment: `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true);` this is all what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add new line symbol:

```
myWriter.write("\n");
```

Or system dependent from `System.lineSeparator()`, but `\n` will always work.

Comment: Still does not work, nothing works.