# to separate new line by FileWriter in java

Tags: java

i am using FileWriter object to write some string in file imtiyaz.txt but i also want to use line separator manually by '\n' but i am not able to separate line by '\n' i know that i can resolve this problem by using BufferedWriter but i want to do by using FileWrite and i wnat to know that is it possible or not if it is not possible then why ?

package first;
import java.io.*;

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("imtiyaz.txt");
        fw.write("hellow imtiyaz \n hi how are you ?");
        fw.write('\n');
        fw.write("i think you are revising java concept");

        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried - fw.write('\r\n');  // \r is the carriage return that you are missing currently

Comment: Yeah it's working, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could enter '\n' at the end of each line. Or write an string consisting of a space to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549704/create-a-new-line-in-javas-filewriter). But, essentially, you will have to use "line.separator" as your "\n" like so:

```
fw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```