# How to add new line on the text file in android

Tags: android

I am writing the data on the file and i am using `ArrayList` for it but my main problem is that how can i add the new line on the text file. Is it possible to do it.

In a such a way that when first data of `ArrayList` write on the text file than automatically in the new line next data of `ArrayList` should be write

```
 final String FILES = "/MY_FILE_FOLDER";

 String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+FILES; // Folder path

 File folderFile = new File(path);
  if (!folderFile.exists()) {
    folderFile.mkdirs();
   }

 File myFile = new File(folderFile, fileName+".doc");
 myFile.createNewFile();

 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
 OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

 for (int i = 0; i < getdata.size(); i++) {
    myOutWriter.append(getdata.get(i)); 
 }


 myOutWriter.close();
 fOut.close();
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
        "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084352/how-to-write-new-line-character-to-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change,

```
for (int i = 0; i < getdata.size(); i++) {
    myOutWriter.append(getdata.get(i)); 
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < getdata.size(); i++) {
    myOutWriter.append(getdata.get(i)); 
    myOutWriter.append("\n\r");
}
```

I Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 6):

Try in this way,

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fOut));

  for (int i = 0; i < getdata.size(); i++) {
    bw.write(getdata.get(i));
    bw.newLine();
  }

bw.close();

fOut.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < getdata.size(); i++) {
    myOutWriter.append(getdata.get(i)); 
    myOutWriter.append("\n\r");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will surely works for anyone..

```
FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(gpxfile);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(writer));
String str ="Apple,Fruit : Cabbage,Vegetable";

StringTokenizer strr = new StringTokenizer(str, ":");
        while (strr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            bw.write(strr.nextToken()+"\r\n");
        }
bw.flush();
writer.flush();
bw.close();
writer.close();
```