# Java, change "println" newline character

Tags: java, newline, println

If I write "`println("string")`" the code writes "string" and then \n if it's run in Windows, \r\n if it's in Linux.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of the "newline" according to my will?
I tried to search some other String method, but couldn't find any that could adapt to this problem.

Obviously the final solution would be "`print("String\r\n")`" if I want the newline to be Windows-compatible, but it's the last thing I'd want to do.

Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Not sure if you change the System property it will be reflect in the "built-in" println() at runtime: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character?rq=1

Comment: Not sure.. but you might want to read some about ascii encoding, I guess

Comment: Its like you want to override your println function. Create your own PrintStream if you want to have custom function.

Comment: how about `print(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`?

Comment: Bruce14: 5 years old question, already seen but I was searching if there were new methods.
Rafa el: exactly what the system already does, and that I'm searching not to do.
PeterMmm: will read about this, thanks

Comment: try `printf("%n")` then

Comment: That's something that I don't want to do, as I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PrintStream uses a BufferedWriter to write, which in turn uses this line separator:

```
/**
 * Line separator string.  This is the value of the line.separator
 * property at the moment that the stream was created.
 */
private String lineSeparator;
```

You can thus use `System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n")` to set the default line separator, but it will only affect newly created PrintStreams (e.g. `System.out` will most likely not be affected).

Comment: Uhm: I don't understand what you mean with System.out not being affected. You mean it's not retroactive, or that there are cases in which the system won't work?

Comment: @user The system property is cached in the stream, thus changing the property will not affect existing streams (i.e. the change is not retroactive).