# Trouble replacing return characters in jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm having trouble replacing return characters in a JTextArea in windows 7.
I have an input textArea that for data storage purposes I want to replace the "\r\n" with a unique string like "#!". Problem is, I can't seem to get it to replace it.

EX of issue:
`JTextArea exampleText = new JTextArea("Enter Text",10,3);` 
`String oneLineOfText = exampleText.getText().replace("\r\n","#!");` 
`System.out.println(oneLineOfText);`

Input:
 
`Text`
 
`Text everywhere`
 
Output: 
`Text` 
`Text everywhere` 
 
Desired Output:
`Text#!Text everywhere`

I feel like I must be doing something really silly. This works perfectly fine in ubuntu when I use "\n" instead of "\r\n".

Comment: `\r\n` I believe is a Windows line ending.  You could use a regular expression to try and trap different terminators, for example `text.replaceAll("\r\n|\n", "#!")`...note - not tested ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, MadProgrammer. This may work except I get this error. "java.lang.string.replaceall(unknown source)". I tried  "\\r\\n|\\n" which also yielded the same error.

Comment: `replaceAll` - Java is case sensitive, I'm assuming your using Java 1.4+

Comment: Whoops, it was actually replaceAll in the code and yes, I'm on 1.7

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, `\r\n` is a Windows line terminator.

Instead of looking for just a single line terminator, you could look for multiples and replace them.

For this you could use a regular expressiong and `String#replaceAll`, for example...

```
//String text = "This is\r\na test\r\nfor some text";
String text = "This is\na test\r\nfor some text";
System.out.println(text);
text = text.replaceAll("\r\n|\n", "#!");
System.out.println(text);
```

Which outputs...

```
This is
a test
for some text
This is#!a test#!for some text
```

You should also note, that not all text editors/text files have the `\r\n` line terminator, but Java does a pretty job of dealing with this...

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard-code the newline character, use the system newline character:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

[How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried. In hindsight, I have an idea of why it may not have worked. Does it grab this when the code is compiled or when the program in executed?

Comment: While it's certainly a good suggestion, what happens when you're dealing with a file from a different OS then the one the JVM is running on, the property becomes irrelevant - just saying ;)

Comment: I figured the replacement was happening on submission of the text box,  which using the system line separator would be perfect for.

Comment: The property is evaluated at runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 0):

open a text file, and save the text of JTextArea in it. Now read the text from the saved text file charater by character by checking the following line,

```
string variable s="";
if(ch=='\n')
   add the #! to the string variable;
```

finally place this string variable to the output section.