# Trouble printing a multiple-line String with PrintWriter into a File

Tags: java, string, printwriter

I'm trying to print a multiple-line String into a PrintWriter, but it doesn't recognizes the different lines.

I have this String: "2\n0 0 1 string1\n0 2 1 string2".

The text I expected to have into the file was:

```
2
0 0 1 string1
0 2 1 string2
```

but it actually is:

```
20 0 1 string10 2 1string2
```

My code is:

```
 public void save(String str){
    try{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
        out.println(str);
        out.close();
        System.out.print(str);
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
```

It's printed OK in the console.

I'm using BlueJ to code. My OS is W7 and I just opened the file with notepad.

SOLVED!

Using "\r\n" instead of just "\n" works properly!

Comment: How do you look at the file contents? What OS are you using? Are you aware that different OS's consider different characters as new line delimiters?

Comment: What platform are you using, and what editor are you looking at the file with, when you see `20 0 1 string10 2 1string2` ?

Comment: I weren't aware about different OS's use different delimeters, but I always used "\n" with w7 and it worked well. I opened the text file with notepad and I use Bluej to code.

Comment: @JoanPuicgerver, Did you try opening with WordPad?

Comment: Also, on windows the standard delimiter is `\r\n`, in other words `CR LF`.

Comment: It's working now with "/r/n"! Thanks @merlin2011

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character

Answer (score 3):

If you want represent literal newlines on Windows, you need to use `\r\n`, which is the standard delimiter for that platform.

In other words, your original string needs to be

```
"2\r\n0 0 1 string1\r\n0 2 1 string2"
```

However, this quickly becomes non-portable, so you should instead query for the standard delimiter first and then use it to construct your string.

```
String d = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String mystr = String.format("2%s0 0 1 string1%s0 2 1 string2", d, d)
```

Moreover, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209771/391161), we can use `%n` format specifier to avoid the call to `getProperty()`.

```
String mystr = String.format("2%n0 0 1 string1%n0 2 1 string2")
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `%n`, not `%%n` on the last two lines?  So `String.format("2%n0 0 1 string1%n0 2 1 string2")` with no need for `d` any more?

Comment: @davidwallace I grabbed that from the linked question. I'll update later if I test and it's wrong. I removed the d though.

Comment: Yeah, the answer you took that from says "use `%n`".  It seems you misread it.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I just got to my computer and tested it and you are correct. My answer has now been edited with the correction. It appears that I misread the example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`PrintWriter.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29) javadoc,

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

So, I think you could use -

```
try{
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
  for (String s : str.split("\n")) {
    out.println(s);
  }
  out.close();
  System.out.print(str);
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

Comment: @JoanPuicgerver: Please consider that `\r\n` is only the proper line terminator for windows. Do not needlessly introduce OS dependencies.