# Does a DataInputStream skip chars?

Tags: java, json, datainputstream

I have an problem with the DataInputStream, it doesn't read the file completly there are every so often (every ~33000 chars) 2-3 chars skipped. I am trying to parse the file (8 mb) as json and with those skipped chars in the string I can't parse the string as json.

```
public static String readTemplate(String templateName) throws IOException
{
    log.info("Opening Template");
    InputStream resStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/"+SpellCraftMod.MODID+"/templates/"+templateName+".json"); // I need to open the file that way
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(resStream);
    String temp = "";
    SpellCraftMod.log.info("Reading Data");
    int available = 0;
    while ((available = in.available()) > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            temp += in.readUTF();
        } catch (EOFException ignore) {}
        log.info("To GO: " + available);
    }
    log.info("Closing File");
    in.close();
    resStream.close();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: are you using `writeUTF()` while writing in the file? why are you using `readUTF()` method?

Comment: @user3218114 no I converted the file to UTF-8 without BOM with Notepad++

Comment: Your JSON parser should be able to read bytes from an Inpustream directly. Why do you read the resource as a String in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet I am using org.json and the constructor is new JSONObject(string json)

Comment: @user3412531: it also takes a JSONTokener as argument, and a JSONTokener takes an InputStream as argument: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28org.json.JSONTokener%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead of `DataInputStream`. The former *reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.*. I would prefer to use `BufferedReader` over `Scanner` for performance matters. Also, use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating `String`s.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(resStream, "UTF-8") );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

If you work with Java 6 or prior, then you have to use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` instead of `System.lineSeparator())`.

More info:

- [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231369/1065197)
- [How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/207947/1065197)

Comment: how do I create one from an InputStream?

Comment: @user3412531 using an InputStreamReader (be careful to specify the correct encoding).

Comment: Works and its SUPER fast

Comment: @user3412531 that's probably for using these two classes `BufferedReader` and `StringBuilder`.

Comment: java has `Files.readAllLines` respectively read the bytes and convert it then (apache commons has the missing function that reads directly into a single string.. annoying omission of the file is particularly large) since java 7 too.

Comment: @Voo I've checked the code of `Files#readAllLines` and uses `BufferedReader` behind the scenes and stores all the data inside a `List<String>` but OP needs it concatenated as a single big String so using this approach will work better.