# Adding New Line in Java String

Tags: java, newline

I want my output to be in multiple lines but `\n` doesn't seem to be working for me. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Hello: name

Weight in Kilograms: XX

Height in meters: XX

BMI: XX

CODE

```
SimpleOutput.showInformation("Hello: " + name \n "Weight in kilograms: " + weightKilograms \n "Height in meters: " + heightMeters \n "BMI: " + (int)bmi);
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: the language is Java

Comment: \n is part of string, so include it in your string "XX\n"

Answer (score 3):

You could use String.format

```
String.format("Hello: %s%n Weight in kilograms: %d%n Height in meters: %d%n  BMI: %d", name, weightKilograms, heightMeters, (int)bmi)
```

This will also give you a platform independent line separator (as opposed to "\n"), see
[How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

Answer (score 2):

\n is part of string, so include it in your string "XX\n" , also add the string concatenation correclty, like:

```
SimpleOutput.showInformation("Hello: " + name + "\nWeight in kilograms: " + weightKilograms + "\nHeight in meters: " + heightMeters  + "\nBMI: " + (int)bmi);
```

Comment: You didn't spell "correclty" correclty.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleOutput.showInformation("Hello: " + name  + "\nWeight in kilograms: " + weightKilograms  + "\nHeight in meters: " + heightMeters + "\nBMI: " + (int)bmi);
```