# Trying to use the printf format to print a 2D array, each row in its own line using a toString() method

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

So I wrote a program that is supposed to take a 2D array as an input and and calculate the sum of each row and each column. Then I need to use a `toString()` method to print the result. For example for the intake:

```
{3,6,8,9},{5,4,3,2}
```

The output should look like this:

```
3 6 8 9 | 26
5 4 3 2 | 14
8 10 11 11 | 40
```

The problem is that I don't have a clue how to print each row in a separate line using the `toString` method. Currently what I have is:

```java
public String toString() {
    String output="";
    for (int i=0;i<resultArray.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<resultArray[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(output+resultArray[i][j]+" ");                 
        }
    }

    return output;          
}
```

Which returns the following: `3 6 8 9 5 4 3 2`
(Don't worry about the summation methods, I have those ready I just need to understand how to format it before i'll use them)

Anyone has an idea how to print each row in its own line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding New Line in Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943597/adding-new-line-in-java-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int[] columns = new int[result.length]
    for (int[] row: resultArray) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            sb.append(row[j])
              .append(' ');
            sum += row[j];
            columns[j] += row[j];
        }
        sb.append("| ")
          .append(sum)
          .append('\n');
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int col: columns) {
        sb.append(col)
          .append(' ');
        total += col;
    }
    sb.append("| ")
      .append(total)
      .append('\n');

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new line after the inner loop:

```java
for (int i=0;i<resultArray.length;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<resultArray[i].length;j++) {
        System.out.print(output+resultArray[i][j]+" ");                 
    }
    System.out.print('\n');                 
}
```

**EDIT :**
New line could be added using `System.out.println()` as well. Even though this works in normal scenarios, it might not work as expected in one case. As the javadoc states for `println()` :

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The
> line separator string is defined by the system property
> line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character
> ('\n')".

So if the same code is run after the `line.separator` property is overriden, then the code will not work as expected. Hence, if a new line is to be added, it is better to use `System.out.print('\n')` or `System.out.print("\n")` instead of `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Thank You! I knew it should be something simple lol

Comment: or just System.out.println();

Comment: @nomad just using`System.out.println()` without passing any arguments works well in normal scenarios, but sometimes it might not work as expected. As the javadoc states - "Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property `line.separator`, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n')". So if the same code is run after the `line.separator` property is overriden, then the code will not work as expected. So it is better to use `System.out.print('\n')` (or `System.out.print("\n")`)