# Storage of /n in String object. Java

Tags: java, string, swing

i have a little missbehaviour in my program.

One of his methods should build an string and then return it to be displayed in an Java Swing GUI.
In some parts of it, it needs to store a "line break" (i dont know the proper name) "/n".

But when i display this string in the gui it contains /n instead of jumping the line properly.

Its a little confusing but with the code i think you can figure it out:

```
public String draw(Robot robot, MapClass mapa) {
        map = mapa.getMapa();
        String mapBuffer = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < mapa.getLinhas(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mapa.getColunas(); j++) {
                if ((i == robot.getPosX()) & (j == robot.getPosY())){
                    System.out.print(robot.convertToChar() + " ");
                    mapBuffer = mapBuffer + robot.convertToChar() + " ";
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
                    mapBuffer = mapBuffer + map[i][j] + " ";
                }   
            }
            mapBuffer = mapBuffer + "/n";
            System.out.println();
        }

        return mapBuffer;
}
```

This string is shown in a swing textArea with:

```
textArea.append(drawer.draw(robot, map));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Line break is `'\n'`, not `'/n'`.

Comment: lol such an stupid error. Thanks -.-

Comment: Also - for efficiency, you should consider using a StringBuilder to build up your return string instead.

Comment: And for platform-independency trade you may want to replace `\n` by `%n` and return `String.format(mapBuffer)`. See [How do I get a platform-independent new line character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `mapBuffer = mapBuffer + "/n";` You are appending to `mapBuffer` the `/n` literal. If you want a line break you should replace it with `\n`

Comment: As stated before, thanks all for awnsering such an stupid error without judging, i cant belive i didnt see that after a lot of time thinking it was a problem with swing...