# java String in following code leak memery? how to fix it

Tags: java, string, memory-leaks

Here is the function:

```
String gen() {
      String raw_content = "";
      String line;
      for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        line = randString();
        raw_content += line + "\n";
      }
      return  raw_content;
}
```

When I call gen() for 100 times in main(), my program will stuck.
I suspect this is related to memory leak caused by Java String. So will the no-longer used memory be freed by JVM automatically? How to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: can you post the code for `randString()`?

Comment: fot the newline character look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/java-how-do-i-get-a-platform-independent-new-line-character

Comment: `line` is completely worthless no?

Comment: There is no memory leak in the code you have shown us.

Comment: In fact I intentionally used the variable "line" since I want to know whether its memery will be freed by JVM automatically.

Comment: Freed when? It's scope is limited to `gen`.

Comment: There is no memory leak,  `raw_content` keeps getting longer and longer, and every iteration involves copying the old String value to a new one.  This drives GC crazy and performance goes into the toilet.  Eventually, if you raised the iteration limit, you would get an out of storage condition because the array was so long, but it would take forever to get there due to the constant copy/GC cycle.

Comment: The only "memory leak" is the _ten thousand_ useless objects you're creating just to throw them away.  The garbage collector isn't magic --- it takes time to clean up all that trash.  You're not "leaking" memory, you're just wasting memory.

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short, in java (and other JVM languages), you don't have to care about memory allocation at all. You really shouldn't be worrying about it - at some time after all references to it have been lost, it'll be freed up by the garbage collecting thread. See: [Garbage Collection in Java](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx).

Your problem has less to do with memory and more that your function is just really time intensive (as Hot Licks said in comment). Strings in Java are immutable, so when you say  `raw_content += line + "\n";` you're really creating a new string of `raw_content + line + "\n"` and setting `raw_content` equal to that. If `rand_string()` returns long results, this will become an egregiously long string. If you really want to perform this function, StringBuilders are the way to go to at least reduce it from O(N^2) to O(N). If you're just looking for a memory exercise, you don't have to actually do any changes - just read the above article.