# Create a new line between strings

Tags: java

In my project, I and taking four strings from text fields and putting them together in a different text field using the setText in Java. 
I need them to be in four different lines, but right now there are all in a line with no spaces between them

How do I break the line between the different strings.

I tried using the `\n`, but I just got an error.

Here is the line of code I am using

```
display.setText(manu+brand+year+price);
```

which gives me this output

```
fordfocus20003500.0
```

I want

```
ford
focus
2000
3500.0
```

Comment: Can you say what error you got?

Comment: have you tried any code?!

Comment: Try `%n` instead of `\n`. Perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character

Comment: the %n does not seem to work, it just gives an error saying create variable n.

Comment: try to append `<br>`between the variables, HTML tags might be supported.

Comment: `I tried using the \n, but I just got an error. ` what error? How did you used it? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: display.setText(manu \n + brand + year + price); gives me the error "n cannot be resolved to a variable".

Answer (score 1):

The \n needs to be quoted because it's not a variable, it's a character:

```
display.setText(manu+"\n"+brand+"\n"+year+"\n"+price);
```

Having said that, I'm not sure what kind of object `display` is, it might not support new lines? What is `display`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [lineseparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) for this

```
String separator = System.lineSeparator();

display.setText(manu + separator + brand + separator + year + separator + price);
```