# Spring Data Rest Custom Method return String

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I need a custom Method on Spring Data Rest that has some kind of input and returns a String.

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping(value = "/businessActions")
public class BusinessActionController implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {


    /**
     * This BusinessAction's purpose is: Generiert für ein Modell das entsprechende Barrakuda-File.
     * It returns one String.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/modellGenerieren", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String modellGenerieren(@Param(value="project") String project) throws IOException {
        // Get project by id from repository and map to string.
        return "asdf\n";
    }
}
```

By using `@BasePathAwareController` the endpoint will return `"asdf\n"`, my desired output would be:

```
asdf
<new line>
```

Im able to produce this output by using only `@Controller`, but this breaks the awareness of the base path and i need the `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` in other methods of this Controller - the assembler cannot be injected then.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character) and see if any of the answers solve your problem.

Comment: @dubonzi   No that doesn't help. The problem is not just the newline character. This is a larger spring data rest issue.

Answer (score 4):

**The Bottom Line**

It can be solved by using the following mapping and configuration:

```
// The OP's original controller with a small tweak
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/businessActions")
public class MyCustomRestEndpoint {

    // Let's specify the #produces type as text/plain (rather than the Spring Data REST JSON default)
    @GetMapping(value = "/modellGenerieren", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> modellGenerieren(@Param(value="project") String project) throws IOException {
        // Get project by id from repository and map to string.
        return ResponseEntity.ok("A String!");
    }

}

@Configuration
public class PlainTextConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    // Allow for plain String responses from Spring via the `text/plain` content type
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters)
    {
        StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(configureMediaTypes());

        messageConverters.add(converter);

    }

    private List<MediaType> configureMediaTypes() {
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1"));
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"));
        mediaTypes.add(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/plain;charset=UTF-16"));
        return mediaTypes;
    }

}
```

And by specifying the `ACCEPT` header when making the request (**this is the key!**):

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/businessActions/modellGenerieren
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept: text/plain
```

This yields the following response:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/businessActions/modellGenerieren

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 24 Dec 2018 06:21:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Accept-Charset: ... <large charset>
Content-Length: 9

A String!

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 151ms; Content length: 9 bytes
```

**The Reason**

Upon investigation, it appears that the reason you can never seem to return the unquoted String is due to the behavior of the [`BasePathAwareHandlerMapping#lookupHandlerMethod`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/BasePathAwareHandlerMapping.java#L90) function.

`lookupHandlerMethod` basically assumes that when making a request on a method, that the permissible media types are made with the HTTP request in the `ACCEPT` header. Otherwise it defaults to the default media type (configurable using `RepositoryRestConfigurer#configureRepositoryRestConfiguration`).

The default value for the default media type for *Spring Data REST* is either `application/json` or `application/hal+json` (depending on that default value, [see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java#L715)). That's why you are ONLY seeing `application/json` content types with the double quote, `""`, around your strings in the result. The `String` is being converted using the `Jackson` converter (which encloses `Strings` with quotes) and not a `String` converter.

After looking into it, I agree with you that this seems like a strange assumption. That is, the framework shouldn't assume that all requests are always explicitly specify the `ACCEPT` header with the desired media type (at least, I personally don't always expect to see it) and otherwise assume that all requests should be of the default media type only specifically because of a use case like yours.

Without looking too deeply into the documetation, the fact that `@BasePathAwareController` seems to imply that more than just the standard Spring Data Rest entities are fair game to use when leveraging Spring Data REST.

I'd personally return the produces type to the client even if the `ACCEPT` header wasn't specified -- and if I were to write some code to modify the `BasePathAwareHandlerMapping`, I'd add the following regarding my commented line:

```
@Override
protected HandlerMethod lookupHandlerMethod(String lookupPath, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    ...

    if (!defaultFound) {
        mediaTypes.add(configuration.getDefaultMediaType());
    }

    // Lookup the Handler Method for this request
    // If no media types are specific in the ACCEPT header of this request...
    // Then look and see if the method has a #produces specified and define that as the ACCEPT type

    super.lookupHandlerMethod(lookupPath, new CustomAcceptHeaderHttpServletRequest(request, mediaTypes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And I have not solved it completely. But I hope this additional info at least helps:

There are 4 annotations in Spring and spring-data-rest that all are IMHO chaotically intermingeled. (See for example this [Bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-972))

[Spring Data Rest controllers: behaviour and usage of @BasePathAwareController, @RepositoryRestController, @Controller and @RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607421/spring-data-rest-controllers-behaviour-and-usage-of-basepathawarecontroller)

If you use `@BasePathAwareController` you get all the magic from Spring-data-rest (see [SDR Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers))  => But then you CANNOT return a simple String. (At least I did not found a way so far.)

If you use `@RestController` then your endpoint is completely indipendent from SDR.

If you want a `@RestController` to be exposed unser the same path prefix as the rest of your SDR API then you can use this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${spring.data.rest.base-path}")
public class MyCustomRestEndpoint { ... }
```

This reads the path prefix from *application.properties*

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api/v17
```

Then you can return a plain String.

But if you use @BasePathAwareController, as the OP said, because you need `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`, then there is no way of returning a plain String.

Comment: digging into the code, it appears to be partially a matter of specifying `ACCEPT` headers; see my answer