# Spring Data Rest controllers: behaviour and usage of @BasePathAwareController, @RepositoryRestController, @Controller and @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to understand the exact behaviour of the Spring Data Rest Controllers.

I have made a simple implementation to test 4 kinds of annotated controllers: `@BasePathAwareController`, `@RepositoryRestController`, `@RestController`, `@Controller`

The controller has a mapping for an entity "author" in the repository.

This is the controller:

```
@BasePathAwareController
//@RepositoryRestController
//@RestController
//@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="authors/mycontroller/test")
    public void handleRequest(){
        System.out.println("handleRequest of class MyController");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/authors/mycontroller/testslash")
    public void handleSlashRequest(){
        System.out.println("handleSlashRequest of class MyController");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="api/authors/mycontroller/test")
    public void handleApiRequest(){
        System.out.println("handleApiRequest of class MyController");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/authors/mycontroller/testslash")
    public void handleSlashApiRequest(){
        System.out.println("handleSlashApiRequest of class MyController");
    }

}
```

I'm testing 4 methods because I have some doubts about the right mapping to be used.

For every experiment, I use a different controller with the sames mappings, simply decommenting the annotation that I need for that experiment.

I'm calling these two URLS with HTTP GET:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/test
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/testslash
```

This is the result that I obtain using `@BasePathAwareController`:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/test
    White page, No errors, No print on console

http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/testslash
    White page, No errors, No print on console
```

This is the result using `@RepositoryRestController`:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/test
    White page, No errors, No print on console

http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/testslash
    White page, and this message on the console (only for the first HTTP GET on this url):
    jul 27, 2016 9:23:57 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myApp/api/authors/mycontroller/testslash] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
```

This is the result if I use `@RestController`:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/test
    White page, in console: "handleRequest of class MyController"

http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/testslash
    White page, in console: "handleSlashRequest of class MyController"
```

Finally, this is the result using `@Controller`:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/test
    HTTP STATUS 404, in console: "handleRequest of class MyController"

http://localhost:8080/myApp/api/mycontroller/testslash
    HTTP STATUS 404, in console: "handleSlashRequest of class MyController"

For both urls I have this warning:

jul 27, 2016 9:28:11 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myApp/api/authors/mycontroller/authors/mycontroller/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
```

I don't understand what's going on.

The only annotation that seems to provide the expected result is the `@RestController`.

`@Controller` apparently seems to work, but I have an HTTP status 404 and there is a message with an inconsistent URL `/myApp/api/authors/mycontroller/authors/mycontroller/test`, despite there is 
the correct handling message on the console.

The other two annotations (`@BasePathAwareController` and `@RepositoryRestController`) don't do nothing.

In summary:

- `@BasePathAwareController`: doesn't do nothing
- `@RepositoryRestController`: doesn't do nothing
- `@Controller`: strange behaviour
- `@RestController`: works perfectly

It would be greatly appreciated any type of clarification about the behaviour and the usage of every kind of @Controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the way to make work all the annotated controllers, and I share it here.

`@BasePathAwareController` and `@RepositoryRestController` **must have a `@RequestMapping` at class level**:

```
@RepositoryRestController
//@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping(value="/authors/mycontroller")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public void handleRequest(){
        //...
    }
}
```

**Without the mapping at class level, both controllers are not handled**.

That's the reason because in my previous tests the methods were never invoked.

The mapping at class level can starts with "/" or not, it works in both cases.

Furthermore, I have noticed that adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` in the configuration context, the warning *"No mapping found for HTTP request with URI"* is vanished.

Comment: Please explain why the docs say 
"This controller (@RepositoryRestController) will be served from the same API base path defined in RepositoryRestConfiguration.setBasePath that is used by all other RESTful endpoints (e.g. /api)". And the code snippet DOES NOT have @RequestMapping on the class level.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers (chapter 15.4)

Comment: wrong, they will be handled from the pluralized domain object class or from the path you specified in `RepositoryRestResource(path=`

Comment: It could depends by the version you are using. With the version I used in that time I solved in this way.

Comment: I opened a spring-data-rest bug for this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1327

Comment: I think the answer is already out of date for Spring Boot 2.5.6
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spring Data REST controller ... must not use @RequestMapping on class level as this would cause double registration with Spring MVC!"

Comment: @Peters_ yes, of course: this answer is right for Spring Boot 1; for newer versions it could be already solved by Spring developers.

Answer (score -3):

As you are using a REST API you need to use @RestController

For further reading check out the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in what conditions is supposed to be used the other ones?

Comment: I have already read the documentation... If I'm here it's because I have a different result despite what is written in the documentation.

Comment: Be careful when overriding Spring data rest repository partially with a controller. You should not use class level mapping. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535