# Line separator in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print some values in new line but for some reason Java doesn't allow me to do it. Value for the second variable shows up in a new line but not for the third one. I've tried `System.getProperty()` and `\n\n` both gives me two new lines while I want just one line separator. 
Below is the code:

```
emailBody.append("Variable1: " + cu.getVariable1() + "\n");
emailBody.append("Variable2: " + cu.getVariable2() + "\n");
emailBody.append("Variable3: " + cu.getVariable3() + "\n");
```

On Console:

Variable1: 1

Variable2: 2 Variable3: 3

I am not sure why Variable3 does not go to the next line.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide more code - emailBody's type and how it is printed to the console.

Comment: did you try using win-style line separator "\r\n"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character

Answer (score 5):

I do it this way

```
private static final String LF = System.getProperty("line.separator");

emailBody.append("Variable1: " + cu.getVariable1() + LF);
emailBody.append("Variable2: " + cu.getVariable2() + LF);
emailBody.append("Variable3: " + cu.getVariable3() + LF);
```

If this does not work, then the problem is else where.