# When i write file I got space in the end How I can change it?

Tags: java

I tried to read content and write it to file.
 The code run on server
when the server is on linux I don't have any problem.
when I run it on windows for any string in the end I got another space 
How I can fix it ?

```
  public static void readFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, boolean closeIn, boolean closeOut) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int read = 0;
    try {
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
    } finally {
        //close input and output
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it's a problem with windows and linux having different line newline characters/character sequences: \n vs \r\n btw: without having a look at your input/output one can only guess what seems to be your problem...

Comment: Open your file with an hexadecimal editor and check wich is the last character, probably is not a standard space.

Comment: I guess you wrtte it is \r\n in windows and \n linux but how I can fix it ?

Comment: I checked it in the console the last character is \r\n in windows case

Comment: Do I need to change the write and read in this case ? meaning that windows and Linux I got different string

Comment: @user1365697 Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character

Comment: The code you have shown does a binary copy of the input stream. No line end conversion is happening. You should get identical results on Linux and Windows.