# Refactor println to avoid repetition.

Tags: java

Im a student working from console and often have to separate my output with an empty line. Im not a big fan of the approach we've learned in the classroom to structure the output. What would be a better approach to this?

```
//code
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("some output");
        System.out.println();

//more code
```

Comment: Did you learn about escape sequences, specifically `\n`?

Comment: just did, from the guy below.

Comment: Kindly refer to [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use character `\n` from [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

```
System.out.println("\nsome output\n");
```

Comment: perfect, your response gives me a space above and below the desired output. that is because you introduced the escape sequences.