# Using BufferedWriter and the newLine attribute to insert a line after a string of text

Tags: java, csv

First off I am new at coding in java.  I have done extensive research prior to posting this question but have not found the exact answer to my question.  I am sure it is my lack of experience, but any assistance the community can provide would be much appreciated.

I am trying to debug a utility class that I have coded.  The code is working except for the bit about adding a new line to the substituted text.

Here is the piece of code that is generating an error in NetBeans IDE.  The error is incompatible types:  Boolean can't be converted to int

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (NewCSVFile),true))
```

What I am trying to do is get this code to read a CSV text file, substitute and the write the new csv data to a new file but preserve the original new lines in the file.  And, I want to ensure that the method used is platform independent thus why I am using BufferedWriter.

Here is all the code for your review.

```
public class TxtFileConverter {

public static void main (String[] args) {

// Location of the file you want to work with.
File CSVFile = new File("/Users/data.csv");
File NewCSVFile = new File("/Users/NewData.csv");
String search = "[,](?!\\w)";
String replace = ",0";

try{
FileReader fr = new FileReader(CSVFile);
String s;
String totalStr = "";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {

    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        totalStr += s;
    }
    totalStr = totalStr.replaceAll(search, replace);
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter
    (NewCSVFile),true)) {
        bw.write(totalStr);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
}catch(IOException e){
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help: [How do I get a platform-dependent new line character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207947/how-do-i-get-a-platform-dependent-new-line-character). Also includes platform independent comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to read some lines from a file and write it to another file. In the output file, you get all the code in a single line.

I think the bug is in this piece of code.

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    totalStr += s;
}
```

If you add a statement to add a new line character after reading a line from input file, you should get the desired output.

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    totalStr += s;
    totalStr += "\n";
}
```

The following code adds a newline character at the end of the file.
        bw.newLine();

Answer (score 0):

What do you think that `true` argument is doing in the `BufferedWriter` constructor? The [second and optional argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#BufferedWriter(java.io.Writer,%20int)) is the buffer size, an integer. You probably don't even need to supply that argument unless you're doing something rather odd.

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NewCSVFile)))
```

Comment: This line produced the same results.  No new lines.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedWriter has only two constructors:

```
public BufferedWriter(Writer out) //sz = defaultCharBufferSize = 8192
public BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz) //sz   Output-buffer size, a positive integer
```

There is no option with second boolean argument. I recommend to use first constructor in your case.